# Change scrollbar size of wxListBox

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm developing an application which has to be used with a touch. For this the standard scrollbar of a wxListBox is too small. So my question: how can I change it programmatically?

Thanks!

Comment: WxGrid class implements its own scrolling. You can use it as example

Comment: @Elmi, wxListBox is a native Windows control. You can't change it L&F. wxGrid is using native ScrolBar control which also won't be changed. Most likely you selection of the toolkit is wrong, or you should look at implementing the scrollbar and scrolling yourself.